# Sort a list by default under specific table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a long list that is being generated by PHP from a MySQL. It has 3 columns and the HTML for it looks roughly like:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="display:none;">IP</th>
        <th>ID</th><th>Status</th>
        <th>Selection</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while($a = $ks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $a['ip'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $a['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo getstatus($a['status']);?></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-status="<?php echo getstatus($a['status']);?>" onclick="redes(this)" value="<?php echo $a['ip'];?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
```

Now, in every table column next to the TH text there are 2 arrows (one up and down) and you can sort them accordingly. I want to know how I can have one row sorted ASC by default when visiting the page?

Comment: something must be generating those arrows. Are you using a client-side table plugin? In which case consult the docs for the plugin to find out how to set the default sort, or how to programatically force a sort at page load. Or, if you don't care about setting the arrows in the UI for this purpose, just put an ORDER BY in the SQL query.

Comment: @ADyson I've tried this, but it either Syntax's out or when it does go through it doesn't sort it. This it the query I would ideally want to use: $con->query("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE regid<>''ORDER BY regid ASC"); but it does nothing. Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean "Syntax's out"?? And also what do you mean by "does nothing". You mean it doesn't work, or it doesn't sort the data? an ORDER BY will always sort the data somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eg.

```
<?php
$sort = $_GET['sort'] ?: 'ip';
$sql  = 'SELECT ip,status,section FROM tab ORDER BY '. $sort;
$ks   = $db->query($sql);
```